Floor vent is blocked with a metal cone - best way to remove it?
We have a floor register in our upstairs bedroom that has never gotten AC or heat. When we looked in the register, we saw the vent is blocked with some sort of metal cone. The cone has screws in it, but they were screwed in from the outside, so I'm not sure how best to remove them. So, a few questions:

Why would someone put this in?
How can we safely remove it?

Note: We replaced the AC and Furnace when we moved into the house, so if this was done for some "airflow balance," I don't think that applies anymore.
Here is a video.


Is it the supply or the return?  Can you get to the screw heads?

I suspect you could probably squeeze some snips in to cut out a piece around the screw head so it's no longer holding the rest of the cone in place.

There is a white something wire looking thing with a hook in the centre.  Maybe for a damper at the end?

That doesn't look like a cone. It looks like more pipe with an elbow. Please take a photo with the important end in focus. Check for a damper near the furnace or just off a trunk.

It’s a supply. I can’t get to the screw heads - they’re on the outside of the vent which isn’t accessible anywhere.
I will try snipping the metal or cutting the screws to get it out. The “white wire” is actually just some dust.

Here is a video of it if that’s helpful: https://jmp.sh/s/a6JhS9tI22kpqjll3o1c

Get your camera to focus further down the duct.

Can you reach in with needle nose pliers and grip the cone edge?  Grip the edge from the top, twist it so it wraps around the pliers, and you might be able to pull the cone off the screws.  Also, we can't see the screw heads, and it's at least possible they don't actually come in from outside the duct.  Then you just could pull it out.  I know that wouldn't make sense, but the whole thing already doesn't make sense, so who knows.

The folded seam in the alleged cone clearly indicates that it's just another section of duct, and drawing the incorrect conclusion from a bad picture (probably Nessie blocking the airflow, or perhaps Bigfoot, the Mothman, or Aliens; all known to photograph with extreme clarity if you simply believe in them. If you rip or cut it out you will still have no airflow but you'll be breaking drywall to gain access to the outside of the now-broken duct to repair it. So skip breaking it and either use a more suitable camera to find the problem, or rip drywall to access it without breaking it first.

There is no "metal cone" visible in the photo nor the video.  The only way you're going to see what's happening from inside the duct is with a very long snake camera.  That sort of thing might be available from your HVAC or plumbing contractor.
If you have access from the air handler/furnace then check the other end of the duct too.

looks like a cone to me

Somebody didn't want any air in that room, abd didn't feel like putting a damper in.
My ducts have always been accessible, but if not either cut the screw, snip the cone, or just pull on it with pliers.

That's a rather troublesome way to block a vent. How do you explain the inbound screws?
